# Understanding shimano brake parts

Tags: shimano, maintenance, parts, brake-levers

I have bought a second hand CUBE Analog (believe the year is 2019 but not certain).
The right hand hydraulic brake lever doesn't have it's top cap and doesn't work.
I'm trying to source parts to replace the lever but I'm a little confused by Shimanos spec list so wondering if anyone could help me.

The recommended brake levers seem to be the [BL-MT201](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/alivio-m3100/BL-MT201.html) with the brake system being BR-MT200.
Is it the case where any mountain bike brake lever could be used? For example, could I go for, what I believe to be, the top of the line [BL-M9100](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/xtr-m9100/BL-M9100.html)?
Should I keep the same naming convention and go for [BL-MT401](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano/BL-MT401.html)?

[Here is the link to the bike page (if it is that year anyway)](https://www.cube.eu/en/2019/bikes/mountainbike/hardtail/analog/cube-analog-blackngreen-2019/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding with the Shimano hydraulic system is that any lever is compatible with any caliper from the entire range (road or mountain).

My suggestion would be to use a lever that is is usually used with a caliper with the same number of pistons as the caliper on your bike to ensure you get the right "feel". This will probably be a single pair of pistons.

It's quite likely this is overcautios advice but other manufacturers such as Magura appear to use different levers for their quad piston brakes.

Comment: Shimano levers are the same hydraulic-wise  except for Saint and Zee, which have longer stroke to get more power.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look and see what I can find.